# Create calendar event using ruby outlook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I am trying create a event in calendar,

Iam able get all the data like calendar,contacts and emails by following below documentaion,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/ruby-tutorial,

But when try to create a event using ruby_outlook getting below error

```
  {"ruby_outlook_error"=>401, 
   "ruby_outlook_response"=>{"error"=>{"code"=>"InvalidAudience", "message"=>"The audience claim value is invalid 'aud'.", 
   "innerError"=>{"requestId"=>"75984820-5241-11ea-b6fc-fc4dd44c1550", "date"=>"2020-02-18T11:26:08"}}}}
```

Below code is for creating event

```
def def index
   token = get_access_token   //getting access token
   if token
      outlook_client = RubyOutlook::Client.new
      event_payload = 
      {
         "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
        "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
        },
        "Start": {
        "DateTime": "2020-03-03T18:00:00",
        "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "End": {
        "DateTime": "2020-03-03T19:00:00",
        "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "Attendees": [
        {
        "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "john@example.com",
        "Name": "John Doe"
        },
        "Type": "Required"
        }
        ]
      }
      outlook_client.create_event(token, event_payload, nil, 'user@domain.com')
   end
end
```

Comment: I think your issue is that the token that you fetched was using the [microsoft graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) but now you are trying to create an even through the Outlook API. You cannot use a token issued for Graph ("aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com") against the Outlook endpoint. You need a token with "aud": "https://outlook.office.com".

Comment: Hi @Gautam, thanks for your reply on this, How can I get token with "aud":"outlook.office.com"

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Better is use the graph API itself to create an event since you already have the token fetched from it. Let me know if you can use the [graph gem](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby)? I have working code for it and I can post it as the asnwer.

Comment: Yes that's goot idea, but I did not find code to create events in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/ruby-tutorial] documentaion, this is about fetchin data.

Comment: Yes @Gautam, I am using **microsoft_graph** gem

Comment: I have posted an answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the token that you fetched was using the [Microsoft graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) but now you are trying to create an even through the Outlook API. You cannot use a `token` issued for `Graph ("aud": "graph.microsoft.com")` against the Outlook endpoint. You need a token with `"aud": "outlook.office.com"`.Better is use the graph API itself using the [graph gem](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby) to create an event since you already have the token fetched from it.

> To do that first create the `MicrosoftGraph` object

```
def create_service_auth
  access_token = get_access_token
  callback =  Proc.new do |r|
    r.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{access_token}"
    r.headers['Content-Type']  = 'application/json'
    r.headers['X-AnchorMailbox'] = "#{ email_of_calendar_for_which_to_create_the_event }"
  end
  @graph = ::MicrosoftGraph.new(base_url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0',
                            cached_metadata_file: File.join(MicrosoftGraph::CACHED_METADATA_DIRECTORY, 'metadata_v1.0.xml'),
                              &callback)
end
```

> Then create the event -

```
def create_event
  event = {
    subject: summary,
    body: {
      content_type: "HTML",
      content: description
    },
    start: {
      date_time: start_time,
      time_zone: timezone
    },
    end: {
      date_time: end_time,
      time_zone: timezone
    },
    response_requested: true,
    organizer: {emailAddress: { name: "#{organizer.full_name}", address: email_of_calendar_for_which_to_create_the_event }},
    attendees: [
      {
        email_address: {
          address: attendee_email,
          name: "#{attendee.full_name}"
        },
        type: "required"
      }
    ]
  }

  result = @graph.me.events.create(event)
end
```